# How to manage "this" binding in method decorator?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-generics

I've been trying to use **this** inside a decorated method with no success. I saw how the compiler translates this and actually it's not using the proper **this**, but a variable called **_this** that is assigned when **this** isn't bind to anything.

I tried to bind descriptor.value to target, but it didn't work

Here is my code:

```js
export function PathMethod<T>(path: string): Function {
    return (target: ServicioRest<T>, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void => {
        const original: Function = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = (entity: T): T => {
            const initialPath: string = this.path;
            if (!this.path.endsWith('/')) {
                this.path += '/';
            }
            this.path += path;
            const result: T = original(entity);
            this.path = initialPath;
            return result;
        };
    };
}
```

And the translation is being this:

```
function PathMethod(path) {
    var _this = this;
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        /** @type {?} */
        var original = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (entity) {
            /** @type {?} */
            var initialPath = _this.path;
            if (!_this.path.endsWith('/')) {
                _this.path += '/';
            }
            _this.path += path;
            /** @type {?} */
            var result = original(entity);
            _this.path = initialPath;
            return result;
        };
    };
}
```

But actually the translation should've been this:

```
function PathMethod(path) {
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        /** @type {?} */
        var original = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (entity) {
            /** @type {?} */
            var initialPath = this.path;
            if (!this.path.endsWith('/')) {
                this.path += '/';
            }
            this.path += path;
            /** @type {?} */
            var result = original(entity);
            this.path = initialPath;
            return result;
        };
    };
}
```

Does somebody know how to manage to that  solution? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to capture `this` from the declaration context use a regular function not an arrow function. The `_this` ts inserts is to emulate the es2015 arrow function behavior. Regular `function` expression and declarations don't do this. While the `=>` is shorter, you should always consider `this` behavior when dealing between the two [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

```
export function PathMethod<T>(path: string): Function {
    return (target: ServicioRest<T>, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void => {
        const original: Function = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (entity: T): T {
            const initialPath: string = this.path;
            if (!this.path.endsWith('/')) {
                this.path += '/';
            }
            this.path += path;
            const result: T = original(entity);
            this.path = initialPath;
            return result;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you so much!

Comment: please consider also refactoring this function. so much mutation and so much going on :/